Can i play a video with exoplayer which is divided into multiple parts?
I have a video(duration - 40 minutes), which is divided into 8 parts, each of 5 minute. I want to play this whole video at a single time. That means i want to provide all 8 parts links once and then exoplayer play it. Is it possible with Exoplayer? Or what approach can i use for this? Plz answer me?
I can only play whole video with single link i.e only one part at a time.
I can play a video's one part at a time.

setMediaItems() is the method you are looking.
it seems possible to achieve this functionality using ExoPlayer. You can create a playlist containing all the parts of your video and play them sequentially. Here's a high-level approach to implement this:
SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(context).build();

// Create MediaItems for each part of the video
List<MediaItem> mediaItems = new ArrayList<>();
for (String partUrl : partUrls) {
    MediaItem mediaItem = MediaItem.fromUri(partUrl);
    mediaItems.add(mediaItem);
}

// Set playlist
player.setMediaItems(mediaItems);

player.prepare();
player.play();

